# Any way to get the truncated text with Selenium in an element which uses css webkit-line-clamp?

Tags: css, selenium, automation, webkit, ui-automation

I'm working with Selenium and trying to get the partial text of a long description which is truncated with the following css: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp

I've read a lot of articles about trying to get the text that preceeds ellipsis when it is truncated and they mention methods to apply in the web element under test along these lines:

- .get_attribute('innerText')
- .get_attribute('innerHTML')
- .get_attribute('value')
- .get_attribute('textContent')
- .text

I've tried them all, and maybe a few others, and they all return the full long description, rather than just the partial part that precees the ellipsis.

Do you know of a way to retrieve that partial text when webkit-line-clamp has been used?

Comment: css only hides parts of the text at screen, but the whole text stands here :( (right click, select all,copy => clamped  text is also copied )

Comment: @mickael Do you have a reference url for us to test?

Comment: @DebanjanB, I found a similar public example here; https://codepen.io/Yukishi/pen/zEBoMr . Having the same problems if I 1st select the iframe which contains the text and then try to get the truncated text. I'm unable to, all methods I've tried just return the complete text (and no mentioned about the ellipsis, truncation, etc)